# Honda Accord 2004 2.4 loud sound after start

Tags: honda, noise, accord, vtec

I have an Accord from 2004 with the 2.4 engine. Today I noticed a very loud noise when I start the car.

Here is a video: https://youtu.be/DUbihM5UmbI

It seems to me, that when the RPM is below the idle, the noise comes back.

Other than the noise, it works normally.

What could this be? VTEC related?

Comment: Sounds exhaust related. Get under the vehicle (suspended safely on jackstands if need be) and take a look. Sounds *way too loud* to be right.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a look tomorrow. Do you think it’s OK to use the car? Could some parts get more damaged?

Comment: If there is an exhaust issue, for the most part it won't cause issues with other parts. If it is exhaust, you shouldn't have any issues using the vehicle. Just pay attention to any exhaust smells, to ensure you aren't venting exhaust into the cabin of the car inadvertently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it that the culprit is the metal sheet under the car. I think it’s for heat protection. It was just loosely hanging there. I mounted it back, but it’s just a temporary solution - I guess it’ll need to be replaced to be able to mount it properly.

[image: Loose metal sheet under the car]